# Minimize bundle with webpack2

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, webpack-2

Is it possible to minimize my bundle file and all of the used modules. I use import in javascript but I want webpack to minimize all the imported js files as well. This means removing all unused code from the imported external libraries. Is this possible. Especially plotly is a really large librarie but I use pie charts only. I don't think my bundle needs all of the code from plotly. Here is my webpack configuration file:

```
const path              = require('path');
const webpack           = require('webpack');
const UglifyJSPlugin    = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
    entry: 
    {
        cash: './js/page/cash.js'
    },
    output: 
    {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: 
    {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'js')
        ],
        alias : {
            knockout: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/knockout-3.4.2.js'),
            moment: path.resolve(__dirname,'js/moment.js')
        }
    },
    module: 
    {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/, 
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true
        }),
        new UglifyJSPlugin({ 
            comments: false,
            sourceMap: false,
            compress: {
                unused: true,
                dead_code: true,
                warnings: false,
                drop_debugger: true,
                conditionals: true,
                evaluate: true,
                drop_console: true,
                sequences: true,
                booleans: true
            },
            mangle: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin()
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to selectively import the members (functions) you require with ES6 `import` [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). [Webpack's documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) describes how. If you do that, Webpack should do the Tree Shaking automagically.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know how to do it when using moment.js? Date conversions needs moment() function which contains all functions for a date object. Is there any import statement to just import some date functions?

Comment: @Gustavo I'm not sure it's possible if you depend on a library that doesn't play nicely. You can try [moment-es6](https://github.com/Agamnentzar/moment-es6) but it doesn't look like that will help based on how it's implemented.

Comment: Okay then maybe there is no chance for some libraries to do further minimization.